# linq to sql orderby date

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table of data which I would like to order by the date. My date field is varchar on the database in the following format; dd/mm/yyyy

I am trying to return my data with the following code;

```
var q = from na in db.NewsArticles orderby (Convert.ToDateTime(na.articleCreated).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) descending select na;
return q;
```

However this throws the following error;

```
Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: this is why dates are stored in the format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skip the `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

```
var q = 
  from na in db.NewsArticles 
  orderby Convert.ToDateTime(na.articleCreated) descending 
  select na;
```

**EDIT**
Since the DB collation does not seem to mach your date formatting, you can try this:

```
var q = db.NewsArticles.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => 
           DateTime.Parse(x, new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).DateTimeFormat))
```

Where "en-GB" is the culture from which your formatting is used. (you might need to change that)

Comment: this throws; The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: I cannot change the column type without losing data, but what collation should i use?

Comment: The best solution is the change the column to a `DateTime`. Or you can try to do the sorting out of the database, see my edit.

Comment: Thx that worked using your edit. I will look into converting the column on the db for a permanent solution.